# Can't export Visual Studio project to Qt Creator

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2008, export, qt-creator, projects-and-solutions

I want to export a visual studio project or the entire solution and I installed the Qt Visual Studio add-in but the menu actions are not clickable:

http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/756/capturebba.png

What can I do to export the project or solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably trying to convert a project that doesn't actually use Qt and there's a bug preventing you to do that. Here is a workaround for **Visual Studio 2008**:

Open yourproject.vcproj file and after the line:

RootNamespace="yourproject"

Add a new attribute like this:

Keyword="Qt4VSv1.0"

And the workaround for **Visual Studio 2010** is (haven't tried this one myself):

1) Open yourproject.vcxproj with a text editor

2) Locate the tag :

3) Between  and  add the following line :
 Qt4VSv1.0

4) Reload your project in VS2010
5) In solution explorer, righ-click on your project
6) In the menu, select "Convert project to Qt Add-in project"

Revise your Qt Project Settings to include the modules you need and then you are ready to go.

Taken from here:

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-27